# Apostrophe adds entries to default.json that should be in database instead

Tags: apostrophe-cms

The title says it all: whenever I create new pieces (from custom modules, e.g. authors, works, etc.) some are added to `default.json`.

This is undesirable, there is no need to save those values in a file ever, since they are part of the database values.

What should I investigate to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are passing piece.title through the __() static text localization helper. Don't do that, it is only for static text. If you wish to make editable content localizable for multiple countries use the apostrophe-workflow module.

If you are seeing this behavior in one of our sample projects though please open a GitHub issue letting us know how and where to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am not yet using the localization method in my code. Could it be that it's used somewhere in the CMS modal itself? If I figure out the pattern, I will indeed open an issue.

Comment: It seems to be when I add new fields to a piece. It takes not only the labels, the help, but also the values of newly created pieces.

Comment: Can you push up a simple project that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: It seems even text input in the search field is added to the default.json. The whole repo is still public at this time: https://github.com/jansensan/arts-et-medias

Comment: Please reproduce this in a simple fork of the apostrophe-boilerplate project. I'm not able to do so so far.

Comment: It seems that using apostrophe-i18n and setting `en` as the default language stopped it from updating the `default.json`. Now it's a cleanup matter, which is not so bad.